# Fetching Data from Webserver onto iPhone returns Garbage values

Tags: iphone, mysql, json

I am using this query to fetch data from webserver onto my iPhone app using JSON Parsing.

```
SELECT a.FundID, a.FundName, a.Strike, a.LongShort, a.Current, a.Points, a.OpenClose
FROM tbl_Positions a, tbl_FundStatic b
WHERE b.FundID = a.FundID
AND b.UserID = '14'
AND a.OpenClose != 'Close'
UNION 
SELECT c.FundID, c.FundName, '0' AS Strike, "-" AS LongShort, b.LastTradePrice, '0' AS Points, "-" AS OpenClose
FROM tbl_FundStatic c, tbl_MarketData b
WHERE c.UserID = '14'
AND b.IndexCode = c.`Index` 
AND c.FundID NOT 
IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT (FundID)
     FROM tbl_Positions
   )
```

Ideally it should return data like

[image]

But it shows junk value (like "MA==",etc) for the columns `Points` and `Strike`.

What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I am using SBJSON Parser.

I am using following code to parse data into JSON String on server side:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        objMyCon.Close();

        String jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        String finalString = "{\"ExecuteTrade\":";
        finalString += jsonString;
        finalString += "}";

        return finalString;
```

**finalString Value**

```
{"ExecuteTrade":[{"FundID":28,"FundName":"Sam Fund 2","Strike":"MTIxMzA=","LongShort":"Long","Current":11985.00,"Points":"LTE0NQ==","OpenClose":"Open"},
{"FundID":27,"FundName":"Sam Fund 1","Strike":"MTE5ODU=","LongShort":"Long","Current":11985.00,"Points":"NTAwMDA=","OpenClose":"Open"},
{"FundID":32,"FundName":"Sam Fund 3","Strike":"MjIwMDA=","LongShort":"Long","Current":14000.00,"Points":"NjAwMA==","OpenClose":"Open"},
{"FundID":45,"FundName":"Rob Fund test","Strike":"OTk5OQ==","LongShort":"NULL","Current":11984.61,"Points":"OTk5OQ==","OpenClose":"NULL"},   
   {"FundID":46,"FundName":"newtestfund5th","Strike":"OTk5OQ==","LongShort":"NULL","Current":11984.61,"Points":"OTk5OQ==","OpenClose":"NULL"}]}
```

This is the Datatable:

[image]

On app side I am using

```
NSDictionary *diction = [responseString JSONValue];
```

**NOTE:** The Query works fine when executed on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my Query to

```
SELECT a.FundID, a.FundName, a.Strike, a.LongShort, a.Current, a.Points, a.OpenClose
FROM tbl_Positions a, tbl_FundStatic b
WHERE b.FundID = a.FundID
AND b.UserID = '14'
AND a.OpenClose != 'Close'
UNION 
SELECT c.FundID, c.FundName, 0 AS Strike, "-" AS LongShort, b.LastTradePrice, 0 AS Points, "-" AS OpenClose
FROM tbl_FundStatic c, tbl_MarketData b
WHERE c.UserID = '14'
AND b.IndexCode = c.`Index` 
AND c.FundID NOT 
IN 
(
      SELECT DISTINCT (FundID)
      FROM tbl_Positions
)
```

Just removed the single quotes `'` around the decimal values.

Comment: Nice work! It's always more satisfying to find the answer oneself.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshoot at each point, before it gets to your iPhone. If you run the query on the database host, what do you get? If you run the query through your web server, what JSON response do you get?

Also, what framework are you using to parse the JSON? Pasting in a code snippet that shows how you're parsing the response may help give more focused answers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick input. I will add the code as soon as possible

Comment: I am using SBJSON Parser. I have edited my question and added the code which takes care of JSON Parsing.

Comment: What JSON string do you send to the iPhone? (What's the value of `finalString` before it gets sent to the iPhone?)

Comment: finalString gives the garbage values for `Points` and `Strike`. The Datatable shows 'System.Byte[]` value in `Strike` and `Points` column what could be wrong?

Comment: I have added `finalString` value to my question.

Comment: I also have tried Convert.ToDecimal and even tried passing a value through a variable. but nothing has helped. Can you please suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: Thanks for your help. I found the answer. Thanks though for showing the way to proceed.  :)